# Catalog price rules with date as conditions cannot possibly work due to strtotime() conversion

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, bug

I reported the following issue as [Magento Issue #9976](https://magento.com/tech-resources/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/1835/) but I'd like to know if a fix for this is in the wild already and I'm just missing it.

---

I'm working on a Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 shop. I must create an additional catalogrule discount on products that have special_from_date attribute set. This is the interesting part of my rule:

[image]

My problem is: this rule doesn't work in a reliable way: sometime it does, sometime it doesn't.

I think I tracked down the issue in a apple-to-orange comparison in `shop/app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Condition/Abstract.php#614`.

As you can see in this debugging session, the function `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product::validateAttribute()` is comparing `$validatedValue <= $value`, where the former ia a unix timestamp (`1504310400`) and the latter is a plain date `2018-01-18`.

The former is coming from the `special_from_date` attribute, the latter is the date set in the rule

[image]

The main issue is that `shop/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php#118` converts the product attribute into a unix timestamp, while no conversion is applied to the conditions of the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Confirmed in 1.9.3.7**

Possible fix:

Change `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product::_prepareDatetimeValue()` to

```
protected function _prepareDatetimeValue($value, $object)
{
    $attribute = $object->getResource()->getAttribute($this->getAttribute());
    if ($attribute && $attribute->getBackendType() == 'datetime') {
        $this->setValue(strtotime($this->getValue())); # added line
        $value = strtotime($value);
    }
    return $value;
}
```

---

**Edit:** this brings up next bug

W/o this change comparison is always `true` for products without "Special Price From" and `false` if a date is set. Result, price rules are

- added for products w/o "Special Price From"
- not added for products with valid "Special Price From"

Seems to be completly wrong. The change from above fixes just the comparison, if a "Special Price From" is set. If not set comparison is still wrong:

> Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Abstract#L610

```
        case '<=': case '>':
            if (!is_scalar($validatedValue)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                $result = $validatedValue <= $value;
            }
            break;
```

Problems:

1. `$value = strtotime($value);` - strtotime return `false` for null or empty value
2. `is_scalar($validatedValue)` - returns `true` if `$validatedValue` is `false`
3. `false` is less the some value, so it returns wrong `$result`

Think *(tested)* this should work:

```
protected function _prepareDatetimeValue($value, $object)
{
    $attribute = $object->getResource()->getAttribute($this->getAttribute());
    if ($attribute && $attribute->getBackendType() == 'datetime') {
        /**
         * seems this was still wrong for empty values
        $this->setValue(strtotime($this->getValue()));
        if (is_scalar($value)) {
            $value = strtotime($value);
        }
        */
        if (!$value) {
            return null;
        }
        $this->setValue(strtotime($this->getValue()));
        $value = strtotime($value);
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the substantial amount of effort you put into this! I'll research everything you wrote and come back to you in a few days.

Comment: Your solution works , thanks! I implemented it on my module: https://github.com/borasocom-team/Magento-DateBasedDiscountRules